# Close form on mouse up event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to close my Form on right click `MouseUp` event. This is the code I use for that matter:

```
MouseHookListener mouseListener = new MouseHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
mouseListener.Enabled = true;            
mouseListener.MouseUp += MouseUp;

private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) Close();
}
```

The problem with this code, is that after the form closes, the right click `MouseUp` fires. So a right click `MouseUp` event fires up in the software, or desktop, that was running behind my form.

How can I suppress/stop that event from firing ?

**Edit:** I am using [GlobalMouseKeyHook library](http://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) to catch mouse events outside of the form. The mouse is never on the form.

**Edit2:** This seems to occur only with right click.

Comment: Normally MouseUp event doen't get raised when form is closed. Probably something else in your code caused it.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev is it really ? I am using https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook

Comment: Hmm...from your original question it was not clear you're trying to catch rightclick outside of your form using some third-party library.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I edited my question, sorry for being unclear

Comment: I would suggest you to use MouseDownExt event & manage right click there

Comment: if your problem is that the wrong Form closes you will have to validate the close is triggering on the right window. But I'm not sure i understand this question 100%

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed How can I manage MouseUp event with `MouseDownExt` ? There is no `MouseUpExt`

Comment: @Shiro MousedownExt event allows you to suppress Right Click(see the demo in your link). so instead of using MouseUp event, try to use this one. to close..

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed I am not trying to close the form on MouseDown event. I want `MouseUp` event. So that doesn't help me here. I know how to use this library

Comment: @FrankJ this indeed was the problem, I figured it out less than a minute ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Handled` in the `MouseEventArgs` to `true`. That should do the trick.

Comment: I did it like this `private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs e) { e.Handled = true; }`

Comment: Just make sure you only do that when you actually close the form and not always, otherwise you kill all RightClick MouseUps everywhere as long as your program is running, or disconnect from the event once you closed your form.